# Magento 2.3.4 and Elasticsearch: Getting a blank result page when searching

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

I am having issues with my company's Magento test site. The issues are when searching using Elastic search, the resulting page is a blank page. Then, when I look for relevant errors in various logs, I see the following PHP error in the /var/log/httpd/error_log file:

```
[php7:error] [pid 22228] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] PHP Fatal error:  
    Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Elasticsearch\\Model\\Adapter\\FieldMapper\\Product\\AttributeProvider::getByAttributeCode() 
    must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/SearchAdapter/Query/Builder/Sort.php 
    on line 92 and defined in /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Adapter/FieldMapper/Product/AttributeProvider.php:72\nStack 
    trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/SearchAdapter/Query/Builder/Sort.php(92): 
    Magento\\Elasticsearch\\Model\\Adapter\\FieldMapper\\Product\\AttributeProvider->getByAttributeCode(NULL)\n#1 
    /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Elasticsearch5/SearchAdapter/Query/Builder.php(91): 
    Magento\\Elasticsearch\\SearchAdapter\\Query\\Builder\\Sort->getSort(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Search\\Request))\n#2 
    /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Elasticsearch5/SearchAdapter/Mapper.php(66): 
    Magento\\Elasticsearch\\Elasticsearch5\\SearchAdapter\\Query\\Builder->initQue in 
    /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Adapter/FieldMapper/Product/AttributeProvider.php 
    on line 72, referer: www.mytestsite.com
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this error?

Now, here is my test site's setup:

PHP version: `7.2.27`

Magento version: `2.3.4 community edition`

OS: `CentOS 7.7.1908`

Elasticsearch: `6.8.7-1`

Also here is further information on my test site's setup: I performed an in-place upgrade where I created the test site from a base Magento 2.3.4 install. Then, added all of the modules I needed. Finally, I copied over a backup of my company's production database and ran the Magento upgrade and compile commands (e.g., "magento setup:upgrade" and "magento setup:di:compile"). And note the production database was based-on Magento 2.3.1.

Thanks in advance for any answer, suggestions, and/or help you can provide.

Regards,

Alvaro

Comment: it may be the any of the third-party module does have compatibility issues in the newly introduced class - Sort.php https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Elasticsearch/SearchAdapter/Query/Builder/Sort.php   Check which ES version configured on the Magento catalog search engine in the system configuration.

Comment: I searched Magento's GitHub issues page and found the exact same issue as I am having: [Magento Issue 27112](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27112). And the issue is currently being worked on, so once again thanks everyone for their help.

Comment: Great this will help someone

Comment: Add a Preference via `di.xml` on this file - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27112#issuecomment-606175216  this may work

Answer (score 0):

This is magento issue. Fixed in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27112#issuecomment-606175216

Comment: It's still not fixed in Magento, unfortunately. The provided patch should work though. There is also an alternative solution for which it suffices to add some `di.xml` instead of patching a PHP file: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27112#issuecomment-922394338

Answer (score -1):

You should disable **module Magento\Elasticsearch**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, when I try to disable the module _Magento\Elasticsearch_, I get an error saying that the _Magento_Elasticsearch6_ is dependent on this module. So, I have to disable the Elastic version 6 module first which does not help.

Comment: please find the line '89 file Sort.php' and run this command: 'if (in_array($item['field'], $this->skippedFields)) {
=>
if (!$item['field'] || in_array($item['field'], $this->skippedFields)) {'